# Javascript drawImage() does not show image in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, drawimage

In my simple test code (HTML and Javascipt) to place an image in a canvas, drawImage() is not working. An image is created in the HTML page but not in the canvas. The code is:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img id = "myImg" src = "testImg.JPG" alt="Cannot find image" width="100" height="100">
    <canvas id = "myCanvas" width="150" height="175" style = "border:5px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      const img = document.getElementById("myImg");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      function showPics(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
      }

      showPics();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Win10 Firefox upon opening the HTML file, the image is shown in the HTML page but not in the canvas. If I refresh, the image does appear in both the page and the canvas.
In my Android 6 phone, the image appears in the HTML page but never in the canvas.
Win10 Firefox screenshots are:
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi887.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8gkx.png)

The impression I have is that the javascript code cannot find the image file even though the image file is in the same folder as the html code.

In Win10 Firefox, what is refresh doing to allow the javascript to access the image file?
In Android 6, why can't it find it at all?

Comment: step 1: put your script in its own file so you can properly work on it in a code editor, and then load it with a script element in the `<head>` using `<script src="yourscript.js" async defer></script>` so that it loads in parallel with your page, but doesn't _run_ until the page is ready to be updated. And that those styles in a CSS files. The reason you want html, css, and js in their own files is because your code editor is _far_ more useful if it can analyse files based on the fact that it's a single language, so it can properly do syntax highlighting, warnings and errors, formatting, etc.

Comment: And then to address the problem: you're running your script without checking if you image is done loading. Just because the `myImg` element exists doesn't mean the image source it points to has finished downloading and has been successfully loaded into the <img> element.

Comment: Thanks. I will add code to check on the loading status.

Comment: Per Mike's suggestion, I added an onload event to check that the image was loaded. The result was that the function was not executed indicating to me that for some reason the javascript code could not find the image file (which is in the same folder as the HTML file. (The new code is included below. The image file is testImg.JPG) Any thoughts on why the image could not be found?

Comment: <html>
<body>
<img id = "myImg" src = "testImg.JPG" alt="Cannot find image" width="100" height="100">
<canvas id = "myCanvas" width="150" height="175" style = "border:5px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
//const img = document.getElementById("myImg");
const img = document.getElementById("myImg").onload = showPics();
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function showPics(){
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
}
//showPics();
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted code. I am new to this group and could not see how to format it. Help with this too please.

Comment: The [markdown explainer](/markdown) has all the details around what codes to use in your post for the various things you might need, and the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) cover how to properly structure your post. Don't put blocks of code in comments: that's not what they're for. [edit] any code relevant to your question into your post.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike thanks for pointing me toward making sure the image was loaded. The following code works.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img
      id="myImg"
      src="testImg.JPG"
      alt="Cannot find image"
      onload="showPics()"
      width="100"
      height="100"
    />
    <canvas
      id="myCanvas"
      width="150"
      height="175"
      style="border: 5px solid #000000"
    ></canvas>
    <script>
      function showPics() {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        const img = document.getElementById("myImg");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend doing this in the modern JS way though, rather than using the [now discourages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers) `onload` HTML attribute. I.e. use a normal `<img>` tag but in your script (which you really should put in its own file and load with `<script src="yourscriptjs" async defer></script>`) you can bind your onload behaviour, and then trigger that with `img.src = img.src`.